# Serving static files in Flask with Content-Length in HTTP response header

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a small Python Flask application which allow people download file from my server. These files will be served by Python, not web server like Nginx or Apache.

I tried to use `send_from_directory()` and `send_file()` and I can download my file but there was no file-size because it was missed the `Content-Length` filed in the Header.

How can I added the header when I use `send_from_directory()` or `send_file()`. Or are there any other better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `send_file()` with a *filename* (not a file object), Flask will automatically set the `Content-Length` header for you.

`send_from_directory()` uses `send_file()` with a filename, so you are set there.

Do make sure you are using Flask 0.10 or newer; the header code was added in that version.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters for your answer. I tried both `send_file()` and `send_from_directory()`, my input is not a file object. But it doesn't work. Here is my code:
`send_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))`
`send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename=filename)`

Comment: @NgoDuyKhanh: what version of Flask are you using? 0.10 definitely sets the header.

Comment: Aha, that is the reason. I am using the older version of Flask. After upgrading to Flask 0.10, the Content-Length was included in the http resonse header when using `send_file()` and `send_from_directory()`
Thank you again @Martijn Pieters